# VBA Solver Function to Loop Through Columns

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, solver

I have a solver function that needs to be applied in 3 columns. I made the following VBA code in order to run the three solver functions with one VBA button.

```
Sub Solver1a()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("B11")
    Solver1b c
End Sub

Sub Solver1b(c As Range)
    Dim m  As Long
    
    For m = 1 To 3
        SolverReset
        
        SolverOk SetCell:=c.Address(), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=c.Offset(5, 0), _
                ByChange:=c.Offset(3, 0).Address(), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
        
        SolverSolve True
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        
        Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Next m
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work when I run the code, it just says "Preparing Problem" in the lower left corner of the spreadsheet. I suppose it's loading but given that is solving three linear problems with no constraints I don't think it should take so long to solve.

Comment: Welcome pythonrookie! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger attached? What line of code exactly causes the issue?